# Prepend to unsigned char pointer in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In C I am reading binary data from a file into a var `data` like this:

```c
unsigned char *data;
data = malloc(size);
int read_size = fread(data, 1, size, fp);
```

I want to prepend the var `data` with `<filename><size>` of the file. How can I achieve this?
It's not a legal C string because it's binary data with null bytes potentially all over the place.

I know to make sure I allocate it with enough memory, I just can't figure out how to actually prepend it.

Comment: What's wrong with `memcpy`

Comment: Is it for later storing/logging or for use by the program?

Comment: Where is the problem ? Be more specific.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `memcpy` might be what I'm looking for. I didn't know about it, I'm a little new to C.

Comment: Say your size can only go up to 99999 and the filename is fred.  Do you want the data to be fred1, or fred00001?  It is easy to preallocate a known size but if it is a variable size, then you need to preallocate the max and start where the data begins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Allocate enough memory to `data`.
2. Copy the prefix into it.
3. Get a reference to just behind what had been copied in 2..
4. Pass this reference to `fread()`.

Comment: In step 3, how do I get a reference to just part of it?

Answer (score 0):

Define your own data format for storage:

```
<uint64_t datalength><string name><char[datalength] contents>
```

Or for easier in-app use:

```
struct named_file {
    char* contents;
    uint64_t datasize;
    char name[]; // contents begin directly after the name.
}
```

1. Allocate the struct with enough space: sizeof(named_file)+strlen(_name)+1+_datasize
2. strcpy(name, _name)
3. contents = name+strlen(name)+1
4. save data to contents-pointer. `memcpy()`, direct reading, whatever.